# How do I stop the screen from being locked on suspend?

Tags: gnome, suspend-resume, screensaver, lock-screen

On GNOME the screen locks when I suspend, and I find that a bit annoying (no one else in the house uses ubuntu anyway haha). What can I do to stop this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### For 11.10

What worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10 is to execute the following in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

You can also install [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) and use dconf-editor to set the same setting manually.

Comment: this also disables the manual lock with ctrl+alt+L. Any ways to disable **only** the automatic lock?

Comment: In order to be able using the manual lock functionality after this fix, you can assign in _System Settings_ -> _Keyboard_ -> _Shortcuts_, _Custom_ the **Ctrl+Alt+L** combination to this command: `gdmflexiserver -xnest`.


Note: I've found the command here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1030073, I'm not sure if on my computer gdm coexists with lightdm, but for me it works.

Comment: it appears that the command ships with lightdm (apt-file search /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/gdmflexiserver), so the suggestion is safe. Jorge, can you please update your answer?

Comment: FYI, this also works for 12.04 (as of the beta at least). That is, both the answer and alexef's fix (except I had to use the command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/gdmflexiserver -xnest rather than just gdmflexiserver -xnest since apparently I have gdm installed too).

Answer (score 19):

### For 13.04

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend 'false'
```

Answer (score 8):

### For 11.04 and earlier:

- Edit your **acpi-support** file by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and pasting

  `gksu gedit /etc/default/acpi-support`
- Find the line that says **LOCK_SCREEN=true** and comment it out to disable screen locking on resume.
  [image]

Comment: This has no effect on my laptop for some reason.  I have to modify gconf-editor entries, as detailed by Jeffrey.

Answer (score 5):

### For 12.04

In the Top-right position of the panel, Click on the Settings Icon, Choose **System Settings**. Choose **System Settings** -> **Brightness and Lock**.

Disable the **Lock** by Clicking on the Toggle Switch Button. This will prevent Automatic lock when system suspends.

*You can of course Lock it by Pressing **Ctrl+Alt+L** Key combination always.*

Answer (score 3):

### For 11.04 and earlier:

Run `gconf-editor`, then under `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lock` uncheck the `suspend` checkbox.

Comment: Been using this method for years, although I actually just tick the "Use Screensaver property" instead, then I can control it with the screensaver gui in system/preferences/screensaver.

Answer (score 2):

### For 11.04 and earlier:

Did you verify that the option in the screen-saver about LOCKING the PC is off. Go to System > Preferences > Screensaver

Verify that **Lock Screen when Screensaver is active** is turned off. Also verify that **Activate Screensaver when computer is idle** is off too.

Looking around i found that you can also edit several Power Management options via the gconf-editor.

Press ALT+F2 and type gconf-editor

Go to:  Apps > Gnome-Power-Manager > Lock

Check the option **use screensaver settings** This way it checks for the option you put in the screensaver window.

There might be other options there that will help you like **gnome_keyring_hibernate** and **gnome_keyring_suspend** (If they use the keyring they might be the ones asking for the password when locked)

This are EXTREME cases please let me know if they work so i can copy them here and make a reference:

First do this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9509427&postcount=10

Then do this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9756347&postcount=11

Comment: I already have it off on both. It only does it on suspend.

Answer (score 2):

### For 11.04 and earlier:

If you disable the screen lock by setting `/desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_lock_screen`, you will not need to unlock the screensaver when you resume from suspend.

```
gconftool -s /desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_lock_screen -t bool true
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2):

On Lubuntu 13.10 :

- Open <kbd>Preferences</kbd>
- Open <kbd>Xfce Power Manager</kbd>
- Open <kbd>? Extended</kbd> and untick <kbd>The Lock screen when going for suspend/hibernate</kbd> box.

Answer (score 1):

**On Ubuntu 22.04:**

Open `Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `Screen` -> `Lock Screen on Suspend`