# Disable locking the screen after resuming from suspend

Tags: password, suspend-resume

One thing I like for MacBooks is that they are usable within a second after opening their lid when they were on stand by.

Ubuntu always requires me to enter my password when I resume from suspend, which can be very annoying.
How can I disable this?

**Related bugs**
It turns out that this really is undesired behavior, and there are several bugs related to this issue.
[Bug #553646 on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-power/+bug/553646)
[Bug #643036 on GNOME bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643036)

Comment: Same question with more solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029696). One could be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start gconf-editor (press ALT-F2, then type `gconf-editor`).

Seach down to Apps/gnome-power-manager, then click on "lock".

You have two choices : either untick "suspend", or tick "use_screensaver_settings" (of course, you'd then have to go to screensaver preferences and remove the "lock screen" option.

[image]

And :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this would be be the perfect answer! If only it would work :(. I have tried both options and neither of them works. Proof: http://imgur.com/w4KVj&Sl385l I would report a bug but I'm not registered on the Gnome bug tracker.

Comment: Note that "suspend" and "hibernate" options are ignored if "screensaver" is ticked.  Try playing with the values and see what happens.  Certainly worked for me, so perhaps a hardware issue?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either :\ (tested it on three different machines)

Comment: This works for me (so far) on : Dell Vostro V13, Toshiba U400, Dell Inspiron, couple of home-built PCs, Acer Revo Ion and a few friends laptops I've built - mostly Toshiba's and Dell's who's models I forget.  I can't understand why this isn't working for people.

Comment: I login manually with unsafe storage and a home-encrypted install, but otherwise largely stock install - 32-bit Ubuntu Desktop edition.

Comment: Yes it is really weired. This bug on launchpad might relate to it https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-power/+bug/553646. I am marking the question as answered as it is indeed the correct procedure, although it might not work on some machines.

Comment: I am using oneiric, and there is no such key in gconf. Any hint? Should I ask a new question?

Comment: Oneiric moved quite a lot of settings to Dconf instead of Gconf.  I think you need to `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`, then run dconf-editor to see if the values are in there.  I'm still running Natty, so can't help here.

Comment: Actually, it seems that turning off screen lock in the screensaver preferences affects the suspend/resume too.  I'll try to confirm this later on using one of my Oneiric laptops, none of which are handy at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

This will disable the locking, altogether, so you won't be able to lock the screen even if you wish to, but if you don't care, just enter these commands. The first commands just gets your current setting, which is likely false:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

regards,

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution mentioned above doens't work for Ubuntu 11.10. Please see [How do I stop the screen from being locked on suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17157/how-do-i-stop-the-screen-from-being-locked-on-suspend) to 'fix' the issue on 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for Ubuntu / Lubuntu / Xubuntu 18.10.

First let's switch away from `light-locker` and `xscreensaver` to the default `gnome-screensaver` as used in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt remove light-locker
sudo apt remove xscreensaver xscreensaver-data
sudo apt install gnome-screensaver
```

Now for `gnome-screensaver`, there is a nice setting to disable lock on suspend that is permanently configured this way:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

To see the other possible settings for `gnome-screensaver`:

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.screensaver
```

Finally, log out from the X11 session and log in again to make the changes effective. The computer will now be usable within a second after resuming from suspend. Great to save energy in my off-grid home in winter :-)

Comment: Thank you, works with my Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

There is more work to do, beyond unticking “use screensaver settings”.

See [Advanced preferences](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-power-manager/stable/preferences-advanced.html.en) for GNOME Power Manager

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to shut down monitor ("lock") and come back without asking for password.

Im using Ubuntu 18.04. After I tired every related settings:

- gnome-control-center

  - users
  - power
  - privacy
- dconf-editor

  - disable-lock-screen
  - ubuntu-lock-on-suspend
  - /org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/

I ended up [crating a new hotkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEphl.png) (lets say <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) that runs this command:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

which "activates the screensaver" in my case it is blank and turns off the monitor.

So I can decide whether I would like to activate basic or password protected lock.

Note <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> activates lock by default:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```