# Can I disable the lock screen that happens when I close my Dell d430?

Tags: 10.10, screen, lock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable locking the screen after resuming from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22735/disable-locking-the-screen-after-resuming-from-suspend)

I would like to be able to bounce straight back to where I left off and the lock screen is just a pain. Please help

Comment: This has already been answered here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/22735/disable-locking-the-screen-after-resuming-from-suspend/22737#22737

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i clearly understand what you're looking for, but i found these:
http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24847/ and
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=0282c09fc59593ce6a3c6c22d2216caa&p=8275103&postcount=1 .

Maybe one of 'em contains the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable it in screensaver settings