# Gnome 3.14: Is possible to disable the lock screen?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, lock-screen

I want to disable the lock screen on Gnome 3.14 after the computer is woken up from suspension. I've tried different proposed solutions, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/22737/171961), but they does now work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disable with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

Enable with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
```

Or reset to the default value `false` with

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend
```

Comment: Give me a ping if my answer works. If it does not work I have to delete them.

Comment: It works. Now I have two answers and both are right :-)

Comment: Mark the answer that fits best for you. And you can also upvote. ;)

Comment: @Manuel Just wanted to point out that our two answers are really the same - just different methods of getting to the same flag in the Ubuntu system

Answer (score 6):

Graphically, use `dconf Editor` to flip the status of `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend` from checked to un-checked

[image]

Comment: Screenshot added ;)