# Can't disable lock-screen in Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: gnome, 15.04, lock-screen

I've read through many of the questions on AskUbuntu about disabling the lock-screen.  Everything I've tried, from setting the lock-screen to "Off" in the Privacy window, to setting the dconf flag:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

Nothing seems to work, still when I close the lid of my laptop and open it the lock-screen appears and asks for my password.

Comment: Did you try with **false**? See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/674837/171961)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to make a difference.  I think either option (gui or gsettings) in theory should work, but there's something in Ubuntu Gnome which is not respecting the user's choice.  I'd like to submit a bug report but I'm not sure what piece of software is causing the problem.

Comment: IF going to suspend on laptop lid close then try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false` If not using suspend then set laptop lid close to `do nothing` (only suspend & do nothing are valid options in org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power,  the others no longer work

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much, I'll add it as an answer to my question.  I guess Ubuntu Gnome is still Ubuntu in some regards.  It'd be nice if the gui was patched to set that flag as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to set the ubuntu-lock-on-suspend flag rather than the disable-lock-screen flag:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

This must arise because Ubuntu Gnome is using Ubuntu to handle to the lid-close and locking mechanism which is not what the Gnome utilities/settings are set to handle.

Comment: You can also have a try with this setting:  org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled