# How to prevent Ubuntu asking for password after laptop lid closed and reopened?

Tags: password, laptop, 17.10, lock-screen, lid

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 on a laptop and I disabled the 'screen lock', but every time I closed and reopened the laptop lid, the system shows me the GDM login and asks for password. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/22735/disable-locking-the-screen-after-resuming-from-suspend

Comment: My laptop never goes to 'suspend' state, the lid turn off only the screen. It's different.

Comment: This may be something that Gnome and [XFCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988446/xubuntu-xfce-closing-lid-locks-screen) have in common.

Answer (score 1):

This disables screen locking altogether, including when closing and opening the lid:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen # Get current setting, should be false

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

source: https://askubuntu.com/a/117276/11929