# Xubuntu (XFCE) closing lid locks screen

Tags: laptop, xfce, monitor, external-monitor, lid

The usual advice is to go to: `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and set `HandleLidSwitch=ignore`, which I already did, and it seems to be working (or my computer wakes up before I can notice it is not up). However, there are additional problems when I close the lid of the laptop:

1. I have a external monitor via HDMI, it goes off
2. I have to open the lid and enter my password again for the monitor to work
3. I have to configure the display again to use the external monitor

How can I close the lid and continue using my laptop with the lid closed normally?

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer that is *not optimal*.

Setting `IgnoreLid=true` in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` closing the lid really does nothing, in fact, not even the screen is turned off (beware of that). Ideally, the screen would be turned off, but nothing else would happen (I would expect to be able to use the external monitor).

Therefore this is not really an answer but a workaround, which may be the best that we have for now.

Comment: This worked for me using an external monitor, on the Display settings, on the Laptop tab, I uncheck Use this display and it turns the laptop one off leaving just the external monitor active

Comment: On my Acer laptop, the laptop screen is still turned off when closing the lid - therefore at least on some laptops, that behaviour is baked into the hardware.  This solved my issues completely - the laptop screen still turns off when closing the lid, and the external monitor stays on and the system does not lock or suspend.