# Disable password request from suspend - 18.04

Tags: suspend, password, lock-screen, 18.04

How can I disable password request after suspend in Ubuntu 18.04? I have already turned off the screen lock but that didn't fix it.

I am new Ubuntu user. There seems to be lots of information on how to fix this in older versions.

Comment: Were are you turning off the screen lock?

Comment: Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Type the following in the terminal after the `$` prompt:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend
```

If the result displayed is `true` then set it to `false` using:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

**NOTE:** The above question and this answer is for **Ubuntu 18.04**.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your directions. The result was true. I put in the command you provided and it responded 
command not found

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Rookie Don't put in the `$` that represents what your display is asking you to enter. I modified the answer to reduce confusion. If this works for you don't forget to accept the answer so others know it works. As a new user you may not be away you can click the check mark beside the answer.

Comment: thank you this works.when you press windows key (super) and l it will lock the system so you can lock it after this.

Comment: Thank you so much been trying to figure this for months :)

Comment: hmm. This didn't work for me on ubuntu 18.10.  The commands described above didn't seem to have any problem.  The first returned a true, I changed it to false, ran the first again and it returned false.  I still have to type in my password when I wake the computer up from a blanked screen.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix same for ubuntu 19.04. does not change.

Comment: Works for 18.04.  I'm surprised it didn't require `sudo`.

Comment: works for 18.04. Thanks a lot!

Comment: mine is false but I still have to type password after suspend?

Answer (score 19):

Disable screen lock after suspend by installing dconf-editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

then navigate to

`org/gnome/desktop/screensaver` and turn off 
`ubuntu-lock-on-suspend`.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

In **Ubuntu 19.04**, there is finally a method to configure this without executing commands:

1. Open the "Settings" program, or start it with `gnome-control-center`.
2. Navigate to "Privacy" and click on "Screen locking".
3. Disable "Lock the screen in standby".

Internally, it has just the same effect as the command mentioned in another answer here:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the password from suspend in 18.04 by going into **Settings** -> **Privacy** -> **Screen Lock** -> [Click he Slider from On to **Off**]

Comment: Did not work for me.  WinEunuuchs2Unix's method worked, but as he notes, one has to remember this.

Comment: this does not stop the screen lock activating when resuming from suspend.

Comment: For me the settings were all gayed out and inaccessible in 18.04. I resolved that by "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false" to make the settings changeable again.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it did work for me -after following the steps it did not prompt me for my password which is what I wanted