# Ubuntu 18.04 lock screen no password

Tags: 18.04, suspend, password, lock-screen

I just installed Ubuntu on my media computer. I would like to be able to login from suspend without writing in the password. Found this thread:
[Disable password request from from suspend - 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029696/disable-password-request-from-from-suspend-18-04)
Somebody already commented on the solution that it didn't work for him/her. I have the same thing. I found another solution of just disabling the lock screen all together. That would be fine by me, but it also doesn't allow me to suspend the computer anymore, and as it is in my bedroom, I would like to be able to suspend it manually instead of waiting 15 minutes until it can autosuspend. Any ideas of what I can do?

Greetings,
Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the **screensaver lock** off by:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

You can turn the **suspend lock** off by:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```

You can lock the screen at will by:

<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: As I understood in other threads, I should write it without the $, right? Didn't work for me with
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled 'false'

Comment: Yes, the $ just indicates you are a regular user in Terminal, not SU

Comment: okay, didn't work though.

Comment: That suspends my computer without me being able to wake it via USB, but with pressing the powerbutton I don't have to put in my password. However otherwise I still have to type my password. Seems to me like a longer solution to start my terminal type in the command, type my password, next time get up to press the powerbutton instead of just simply typing in the password when waking up...

Comment: Oh, maybe I am an idiot. I use the lock button on the top right, where you would also shut down the computer. Is that some other funktion? Hovering over it didn't give me more info like it would in windows.

Comment: What happens when you press: SUPER (Windows Button)+L ? It should just lock your screen.

Comment: Locks the screen, then screen gos black and monitor says "no input". When waking it up with USB keyboard I gotta put in my password.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it through GUI.**

1. Settings -> Privacy -> `Screen lock`
2. Click `Screen Lock`
3. Set Automatic screen Lock `off`

That is it!

Comment: Tried that already, didn't work though.

Comment: Works like a charm in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Okay, don't know why this all is not standard, but I got it now how I want it.

Step 1:
Added a suspend button
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/826/suspend-button/

Step 2:
Wake up computer via USB
[Wake up from suspend using wireless USB keyboard or mouse (for any Linux Distro)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848698/wake-up-from-suspend-using-wireless-usb-keyboard-or-mouse-for-any-linux-distro)

Step 3:
Disable The Lock button, so nobody touches that
[Disabling Lock Screen 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048774/disabling-lock-screen-18-04)

Step 4:
Stop asking for passwords after suspend
Broadswordes comment:
You can turn the screensaver lock off by:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```

You can turn the suspend lock off by:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```