# Stop Ubuntu 19.10 from asking for password from screen lock

Tags: login, suspend, password, lock-screen

I've seen quite a few similar questions on here, but none seem to solve my issue (or I am misapplying the answers).

I'm running a laptop on Ubuntu 19.10 largely as a media server, and am looking for the following security settings:

- On startup, require password to log in
- Require `sudo` password for changing settings, installing software etc.; BUT
- Don't require password to sign in after screen lock

I have set

```
nils@nils-HP-EliteBook-2560p:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend
false
```

As suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029696/disable-password-request-from-from-suspend-18-04) but this works only occasionally - after longer periods of inactivity, it still requires a password login.

Is this combination of password requirements feasible?

Comment: Okay so you're saying there's "screen lock" and "suspend/hibernate" lock? If so is there a way to distinguish password requirements for restart and software installations from suspend/hibernate? Also, the "inactivity" in my case includes playing music through a media player, would this still be affected by suspend/hibernate?

Comment: Nope and that is not considered inactivity: inactivity means that the machine is doing nothing.

Comment: Hm that's even more confusing - so currently I am listening to music, and when I step away for a few minutes the screen turns off, upon pressing a key I get to the lock screen and have to enter my password. Which setting affects this behaviour?

Comment: Install tweaks. It has an option for lock screen that I never saw elsewhere. Oh and looking at your command you use lockonsuspend. You also need the normal one

Answer (score 0):

Privacy" and turn off "Screen Lock" to disable the screen lock from being activated when your screen is blanked.

This will not prevent your lock screen from being activated when your computer resumes from hibernation or suspend.

To also disable the lock screen when resuming from suspend, set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend to false, as in

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
```