# how can I do away with having to put in a password every time my computer goes to sleep, in Ubuntu?

Tags: suspend

I'd like to know if there's a way to do a way with the need to put my password in every time my computer goes to sleep.  My computer is private enough - I don't have a business.   I just use it in my home.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable password request from suspend - 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029696/disable-password-request-from-suspend-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well.

This [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029696/disable-password-request-from-suspend-18-04) should fix your problem. Remember to search for answers to your problem before asking a question. Most of the time, if it is not something too advanced/specific, you will find another already-answered forum.

Hope this helps,
Bubbles

Comment: Link-only answers are low quality. If this is a duplicate question that already has a good answer, you should flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm guessing they don't have 'duplicate marking' permissions, have done it myself.

Comment: I see. This is good to know for next time, thank you.