# How can I prevent the screen from being locked after resuming from suspend

Tags: suspend-resume

After upgrading to ubuntu 11.10 my screen locks after resuming from suspend. Unticking autolock in gconfig doesnt work anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/17157/how-do-i-stop-the-screen-from-being-locked-on-suspend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following in terminal and it worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-tools
```

(
the equivalent terminal command is:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

)

Here's a picture of mine:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in **system settings -> screen**

change the lock toggle to off

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmmm worked for me, but im using gnome-shell.