# How can I disable lock on resume in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, lock-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the screen from being locked on suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17157/how-do-i-stop-the-screen-from-being-locked-on-suspend)

since my upgrade to Oneiric I haven't been able to figure out how to re-disable locking the computer after resuming. Ordinarily I could use gconf-editor to tell the system but that doesn't work now. How can I bring back that functionality?

Comment: None of the solutions of the above worked for me, sadly.

Comment: I put a bounty on it to get some attention.