# How do I disable "Lock screen" keyboard shortcut under Unity?

Tags: shortcut-keys, lock-screen, system-settings

I don't want <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (that is the windows key pressed with the L key) to lock my screen. I have disabled this in settings, but it still happens. How do I make this not happen?

[image]

Comment: what is your output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen`? I can disable it by `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true`, but the screen still turns black for a while...

Comment: Are you using Unity or Gnome Shell? They both have their own problems with hard to remove default keyboard short cuts.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I am using Unity. I updated my question title.

Comment: Some may think that this is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/17157/1879 , but I don't think that it is although it has the same solution. What do other members of the community think?

Comment: @kzh: Can you include the info about your desktop environment in you question please? It may be relevant for people who know the answer or have the same problem.

Comment: great that it works, just posted it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to see what is the current setting by the command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

The output should be:

```
true
```

If it isn't, you can set it by the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

A cosmetic downside on my system is however that the screen doesn't lock any more, but still turns black for a second or so. You'll have to see if it works well on your system.

Comment: This does the trick. I assume that the answer is yes, but are these changes persistent?

Comment: @kzh Yes, the change is persistent.

Comment: @kzh on my system it is, let me know if it isn't, I'll make a workaround

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks for the offer, but I think that it is persistent and if not, I am sure I can come up with something.

Comment: This is only a half-way solution. The black screen is not helpful. What worked (in 16.04 LTS) was disabling the shortcut through the Compiz config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224554/200987

Comment: This solution caused my computer to remain UNLOCKED when resuming from sleep, even though I have set it to be password protected. So, in my case, this solution is unacceptable.

Answer (score 5):

A fix on Ubuntu 16.04 that does not turn your screen black is disabling the key setting using the Compiz configuration manager. Turns out it is not Gnome, but Compiz, that captures the key combo. This is why disabling the shortcut does not work. [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224554/200987) covers how to do it.

The package is called `compizconfig-settings-manager` and I only managed to find it using the GUI app launcher. To reproduce the steps here:

- Install and run CompizConfig Settings Manager
- Click "Ubuntu Unity Plugin"
- Click the button next to "Key to lock the screen."
- Disable

Comment: Works great without the black screen flash!  next I just need to find out what it is setting so I can just configure it via vim or emacs or from the command line