# Hidden keyboard shortcut for screen Lock

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

I want to unbind <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> from "screen lock". I removed original binding in "System settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> system -> lock screen" but it still locks my screen. I tried to look in `dconf` and `gsettings` (based on several search results here in Stack Exchange) but couldn't find relevant shortcut definitions. Are there other places to check?

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Edit: This is a duplicate except that the best answer of the original question didn't solve my problem. This did: https://askubuntu.com/a/919988/741512

Comment: I couldn't find it there. Also the other place I looked was "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys"

Comment: Are you sure you don't have this option in dconf-editor? I have a 16.04, it is [present in my settings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xm6tpsrh0an275f/Sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o_007.jpg?dl=0).

Comment: You can try to create an empty Custom Shortcut. Into the command field type just `echo`, for example, and assign `ctrl`+`alt`+`L` to it. If this trick works, remove the new empty CS.

Comment: Redbob Yes, I can locate "org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings" in dconf but nothing inside appears to be the thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I found this https://askubuntu.com/a/919988/741512.
So I was able to find the 'hidden' shortcut in CompizConfig Settings Manager -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin.