# How do I stop the screen from being locked on resume on Kubuntu/KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, kde, lock-screen

Per [How do I stop the screen from being locked on suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17157/how-do-i-stop-the-screen-from-being-locked-on-suspend) I want to be able to sleep and resume without the screen locking.

All the previous answers seem to involve fairly Gnome-specific things that won't apply to me but please correct me if I'm incorrect in that assumption!

Comment: Are you not just able to do `Power management -> Advanced settings -> uncheck "lock screen on resume"`?

Comment: @Toroidal Yes, yes I am. I didn't know that existed. Spin that into an answer and you have a quick 25+rep

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To make it so that it does not lock on resume do the following: `Power management → Advanced settings`  and uncheck "Lock screen on resume"

**Note for 15.04**: This has moved to `Desktop Behaviour → Screen Locking`.

[image: Advanced Settings Area]