# How to enable automatic login after suspend in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: gnome, login, 17.04, auto-login

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on Asus UX305.

I would like to enable automatic login after waking up from suspend (so I don't have to enter the password).

I have enabled "Automatic Login" in Settings->Users (I have only one user on this machine), but it doesn't work - after waking up from suspend (and restarting) I need to enter password to log in. Any ideas on how to debug/fix this?

Answer (score 6):

This issue is same as here: [How do I stop the screen from being locked on suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17157/how-do-i-stop-the-screen-from-being-locked-on-suspend#70295)

---

You can disable the lock on suspend:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend 'false'
```

OR completely disable the whole lock screen:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```